# Github Build and Deploy Error: No uploaded artifact was found

Tags: github, deployment, build, artifact

I am trying to deploy a github.io blog but having an issue with build and deployment. I can build the files without any issue on local server, but when I try to publish it on github server by pushing it, it throws a build and deployment error saying:

> Error: Error: No uploaded artifact was found!

[image: img]

Here's my git repo link for more info: https://github.com/dailyole/dailyole.github.io/runs/4677505925?check_suite_focus=true

I was able to publish the same files on github.io without an issue a few weeks ago, but it throws an error now.

Comment: I'm having the same problem for my site: https://github.com/catalin-hritcu/catalin-hritcu.github.io/runs/4679816346?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: For what it's worth clicking on the "Artifact URL" in the link above shows me the following "innerException":

{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The user 'System:PublicAccess;aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"UnauthorizedRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

Comment: Just started receiving this error recently too after years of successful builds for `github-pages`, and it's not a submodule issue,  https://github.com/boycce/monastery/deployments/activity_log?environment=github-pages

Comment: @RickyBoyce I can't still figure out how to solve this. Please share with us if you end up resolving the issue. thanks :)

Comment: YMMV, but switching the source branch to gh-pages from master (see https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source) solved this issue for me. I do not know if this is applicable to all the scenarios mentioned here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, found a solution here (at least for my case). I just needed to comment out the theme in my `_config.yml` file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case my problem was caused by some bad submodule references:
https://github.com/catalin-hritcu/catalin-hritcu.github.io/actions/runs/1643762494

```
No url found for submodule path 'teaching/epit2018' in .gitmodules
```

This seems to be a common issue these days:
https://github.community/t/failed-to-publish-static-site-spa-with-submodules/219880

It fixed it with some commands like this:

```
git rm --cached teaching/epit2018
```

This doesn't seem the problem for you though.

Answer (score 1):

solved it by change the theme of blog.

## methed 1: change it in web by settings.

1. On GitHub, navigate to your site's repository.
2. Under your repository name, click  Settings.
   [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PrmL.png)
3. In the "Code and automation" section of the sidebar, click  "Pages",
4. then, click "change theme"
   [change theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHvls.png)
5. select one theme, and click "select theme"
   [select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWLz9.png)

## methed 2: change in the file

```
vim  _config.yml
```

change the line

```
theme: jekyll-text-theme
```

to a new theme, like

```
theme: jekyll-theme-cayman
```

: sorry for `I need at least 10 reputation to post images`

Comment: Now you can post images?

Answer (score 0):

Realized this issue occurs when there is an empty submodule in your GitHub repo. Removed the empty submodule and it's working now.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to tell me how to remove the empty submodule in my Github repo?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue the first time right now I used v3 of a github action and wanted to check v4 so i switched to it and this error showed up i tried going back to v3 and the error still shows up

(i even copied the entire file from a commit before the change just to be sane)

i fixed it by going to pages and unpublishing the site and also using the branch for deployments insted of github actions then going back to github action deployments and thats fixed it

for me i think it was a problem about caching ig?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see, your problem is different than mine though:
https://github.com/dailyole/dailyole.github.io/runs/4677504175?check_suite_focus=true

```
github-pages 223 | Error:  The jekyll-theme-hydejack theme could not be found.
```

Answer (score -1):

I also meet the question, and my git repo is: `github-pages 223 | Error:  File to import not found or unreadable: mixins/reset-filter.`
Then I see the path that have the problem, I found this file isn't uploaded. The folder contains too many files and I didn't check it again. May be you need to check if some files are not uploaded.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).