# sudden github page error: Github Build and Deploy Error: No uploaded artifact was found

Tags: github, deployment, build, artifact

There was no problem for me committing and pushing my changes to my github page but suddenly it failed with this error Github Build and Deploy Error: No uploaded artifact was found.
Here is the github page workflow: https://github.com/brian6484/brian6484.github.io/actions
I have looked at similar question posed by [Github Build and Deploy Error: No uploaded artifact was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70568350/github-build-and-deploy-error-no-uploaded-artifact-was-found) but my issue seems different from his because mine failed halfway. What is this artifact that I am missing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh finally found the solution. The build tab on the right (not the default deploy tab) in workflow page shows the cause of error and mine was this

> Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 147): Unknown tag 'endhighlight' error

, which was caused when I was incorrectly formatting my code in md file. Hope this helps someone with similar issue! :)